# How can i slide up data-role="content" in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here my problem is i want to give slide up effect to all elements inside data-role content.
  I  can create a similar effect using two different page .

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage" >
 </div>
 <div data-role="page" id="secondpage" >
    <div data-role="content"   id="projector">
    <ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

$("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
     $.mobile.changePage("#secondpage", { transition : 'slideup'});

});
```

But how can i do it in a single page?

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage" >
<div data-role="content"   id="projector">
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

$("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
      $('#projector').slideup(2000);

});
```

The above code is not giving the expected effect

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You want to apply slideup effect to all data-role divs, then you can write like this

```
   <div data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="content"   id="projector">
    <ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    $("#firstpage").live('pageinit', function (evt) {
          $("div[data-role='content']").slideup(2000);

    });
```

[more details check this Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"] post](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

### Solutions

There are 2 nifty methods built for jQM that enables scrolling:

#### $.mobile.silentScroll

Example:

```
//scroll to Y 100px
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

This will scroll according to your page content so you don't need to target a page. More abot this method cena be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

#### scrollTop(value)

Example:

```
$("div.demo").scrollTop(300);
```

This one is from the point of reference and you will need to do it on some page element. More about this one can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/scrollTop/index.html

### More info

If you want to find out more about this topic take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-scroll-to-the-top-before-page-transition-in-jquery-mobile/)**, you will also find working examples.